# Prioritize items on Xapian query

Tags: python, tf-idf, xapian

I am currently using Xapian to perform some queries over Debian packages. I am using the tfidf algorithm to weight package terms over all my installed packages and then I search the apt-xapian-index with the terms with most significant weight.

However, when I perform the Xapian query, the weight of my terms are not considered. Therefore, the query make does not prioritize the term with most weight, it assumes that all terms are equals.

I am using the python binding for Xapian and I do like to know if there is a way to consider the terms weights on a Xapian query.

Comment: Give an example for queries with weight that you have tried?

Comment: For example, I have tried to parse the Debian package database with some debtags, such as devel::machinecode, devel::code-generator.

So basically I create a list containing the debtags and create a xapian.Query object with using the OP_OR flag. But the thing is that I would like my query to prioritize some debtags over others and I really don't know if that's possible.